# "Prevalent" vs "prevailing"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

What is the difference in meaning between *prevalent* and *prevailing*? I'm not sure I get the nuance, if there is one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The copy of the *NOAD* (*New Oxford American Dictionary*) installed on my *Mac Mini* (the computer I am using to post this answer) has the following example about the usage of *prevalent* and *prevailing*.

> Wildflowers might be prevalent in the mountains during the spring months, but a particular type of wildflower might be the prevailing one.

It then adds the following explanation.

> *Prevalent*, in other words, implies widespread occurrence or acceptance in a particular place or time (*a prevalent belief during the nineteenth century*), while *prevailing* suggests that something exists in such quantity that it surpasses or leads all others in acceptance, usage, or belief (*the prevailing theory about the evolution of man*).

Answer (score 12):

In my own words, here is an easy, albeit simplistic, way to differentiate between the two:

- **prevailing**:  dominating, e.g. *prevailing factors*, *prevailing army*
- **prevalent**: widespread, e.g. *malaria is prevalent in the tropics*