# Is "helped paved" construction correct? (It's very prevalent—perhaps it's dated?)

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, past-tense

I am proofreading a text with the following sentence: "By the time Henry died, he had helped paved the way for the future of economics."

If "helped paved" is incorrect (and should be "helped pave" instead), why does the internet list so many published instances of it? Please see link:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22helped+paved%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj33fP01P_gAhWl8oMKHelOAAkQ_AUIFCgB&biw=1261&bih=718

Thank you very much!

Comment: "helped pave" is correct, and there may be many instances of the incorrrect version due to plagiarism — website authors blindly copying content fom other sites.

Comment: Because there are a lot of poorly edited books, presumably.

Comment: [Common is not the same as prevalent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=helped+paved%2C+helped+pave&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: Interestingly, Ngram finds almost no uses prior to 1974, but after that date usage skyrocketed.  I'm guessing that "helped paved" somehow made it into Indian or Chinese English, or one of the other dialects.

Comment: I will note that, in dictation, "helped pave the ..." will often sound very close to "helped paved the ...".  Of course, a good stenographer would catch this, either in the original dictation or during subsequent editing, but I suppose not all stenographers are that good.

Comment: @choster: what do you mean? I almost asked a separate question about the meaning of "common" vs. "prevalent", but then I thought that maybe you meant to refer to the "vulgar" or "mediocre" sense of the word *common.* If not, I'm confused. The answers to [“Prevalent” vs “prevailing”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12337/prevalent-vs-prevailing) indicate that the word "prevalent" does not imply that something is more common than the alternatives.

Comment: @sumelic *Prevalent* signifies something dominant, or overwhelmingly widespread; *common* simply means well-known or appearing frequently. The OP has established that "helped paved" is common, in that there are at least thousands of examples in print. The NGram supports my position that it is not prevalent.

Comment: @choster: I can't find a dictionary that says that it is incorrect to use "prevalent" in the sense "widespread" as opposed to "overwhelmingly widespread". [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/prevalent) says that "predominant, powerful" is an archaic meaning of *prevalent,* not the current meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that since "helped paved" is probably always followed by "the", then given that the spoken utterance "helped paved the" is almost indistinguishable from from "helped pave the", that the grammatically wrong form has always sounded (more or less) correct.

Isn't it probable that this detestable habit has something to do with the spell-checking apps we all have to use now?

Comment: This mistake became popular in the 70s, well before spell-checking apps were common, much less grammar-checking apps.

Comment: @HotLicks Do you mean "popular" or "frequent" :-)

Comment: @BoldBen - Whichever you prefer.

Comment: @I'd go with "frequent". It's not popular with me. 